# Android Studio > DDMS > File Explorer has no content

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have an emulator running on API 24 - Android 7.0:

[image: snapshot 1]

When I started the DDMS through Android Studio Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor, the file explorer has no content inside it.

[image: snapshot 2]

But when I go to emulator settings it shows that, there is a SD card inside the emulator.

[image: snapshot 3]  [image: snapshot 4]

I have done the ADB restart using the following commands but it didn't fix my issue.

> adb kill-server
>
> adb start-server

How can I fix this issue?

UPDATE: Does anyone know the answer for this issue ?.

Comment: if you are using AVD it will show nothing because you need root acess. Try genymotion...Genymotion is by default rooted so you can see file explorer by default

Comment: @KostasDrak: I have looked into Genymotion, to use it we have to buy it. Do you know any other free android emulators I can use instead of AVD.

Comment: if you want to use it for a company then yes you would have to buy it. If you want to use it for yourself then its free. You can try also Bluestacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy Process. You go into https://www.genymotion.com/
 and create an account. Then you download genymotion with or without VirtualBox.

The in the Android Studio you to:

File->Settings->Plugins->Browse Repositories and search for genymotion and you should come with a screen like this:

[image]

after you install and restart Android Studio you have to click the pink icon or go to File->Settings->Other Settings->Genymotion and set the path that you installed it. Then you will add a device and when its ready you should have this emulator:

[image]

and then you will be able to see the file explorer files:

[image]

PS. Genymotion is way faster than the original AVD. If you want more advanced features though i suggest buying it!!!

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Still I can't see any content in the DDMS File explorer for virtual device on API 24 ?. But I was able to see the content for virtual device on API 21. Do you know a solution ?

Comment: Is it something to do with the API version ?

Comment: i dont think that it has to do something with the API version. Its strange though.

Comment: You also have created the virtual device with API 21 not with API 24. I created a virtual device with API 21 using AVD. Once I started the virtual device I look into File Explorer in DDMS, it displayed the content. I think this has to with the API version I guess. Do you know a work around for this ?.

Comment: didnt really faced this error before so i dont know how to solve it